# ES: Index template does not convert from UNIX timestamp to date

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am inserting documents coming from Apache Spark via Structured Streaming into ES.

Unfortunately, there is an unsolved bug in the Spark-ES connector (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/1173) which has the negative effect that date fields on source side (Spark) are sent as unix-timestamps/long types into the sink (ES).

I thought that an index template for converting it on ES-side might be a good workaround for having it in the correct format (date) in ES.

My index template is:

```
{
  "index_patterns": "my_index_*",
  "mappings": {
    "peerType_count": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "timestamps": {
            "path_match": "*.window.*",
            "match_mapping_type": "long",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But the document in ES has still the unix timestamp in it :-/

```
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_type": "peerType_count",
  "_id": "kUGWNmcBtkL7EG0gS280",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "window": {
      "start": 1535958000000,
      "end": 1535958300000
    },
    "input__source_peerType": "peer2",
    "count": 1
  }
}
```

Does somebody has an idea what might be wrong?

PS: Is there any good es-mapping-debugger out there available?

Comment: A dynamic template will never change the source document you're sending, it will only take actions on the underlying mapping. However, you might want to look into an ingest pipeline and more specifically the [`date` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-processor.html) which might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks Val, will have a look and update this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want to share my workaround, just create an ingest pipeline in ES with following http request:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/fix_date_1173
{
    "description": "converts from unix ms to date, workaround for https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/1173",
    "processors": [
      {
        "date": {
          "field": "window.start",
          "formats": ["UNIX_MS"],
          "target_field":"window.start"
        }
      },
      {
        "date": {
          "field": "window.end",
          "formats": ["UNIX_MS"],
          "target_field":"window.end"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

and enable it in your spark code by

```
.option("es.ingest.pipeline", "fix_date_1173")
```

Thanks @val for the hint!